# Call Jquery in .Net in a Switch Case

Tags: jquery, .net, switch-statement

What is a good way to attach a client-side Jquery call inside the change event of a ASP dropdownlist?

I have read that the registerstartupscript is obsolete, but I do not see what is the better way to do that now. I want to mix JQ in the code behind so that it will be easier to maintain. Rather than doing a check inside of a JQ block to detect a change in the select and then calling toggle()

Is there a better way than this? What is the new way that replaces the obsolete register script methods?

```
protected void SearchDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            switch (SearchDropDown.SelectedItem.Value)
            {
                case "Category":
                    CategorySearch.Visible = true;
                    NameSearch.Visible = false;
                    SearchText.Visible = false;
                    Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>$('#category-container').toggle();</script>");
                    break;
                case "Name":
                    NameSearch.Visible = true;
                    CategorySearch.Visible = false;
                    SearchText.Visible = false;
                    Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>$('#name-container').toggle();</script>");
                    break;
                default:
                    SearchText.Visible = true;
                    NameSearch.Visible = false;
                    CategorySearch.Visible = false;
                    Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>$('#search-container').toggle();</script>");
                    break;
            }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it all client-side in jQuery.  I think that is the simplest way you could do it.  I don't think I've ever seen the mix of Javascript in code making things easier to maintain.  In fact, I'd say it makes things harder to maintain.

Not to mention, doing all of this client-side will be faster and a better experience for the user to not have to have wait for a post-back/page load.

Comment: Will the above work though? There is already clientside stuff happening in the code behind, which is why I was hoping to keep it all there inside that switch case.

Comment: I think you'll get an error if you use the above code because Response.Write will write the script tags out immediately which is before the actual HTML gets written.  If you want to use the approach above you'll need to use one the ScriptManager methods.  I think this is the one you will want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408.aspx    Also, you have a typo in your open script tag.  You are missing the 't' in script